# Python: Nonsensical edge addresses when using bmesh.ops.create_circle

Tags: python, add-on, bmesh

**TL;DR:** Two different faces created using `bmesh.ops.create_circle` have the same edges... sort of?

```py
# create 2 circles
circ1 = bops.create_circle(bm,
                           cap_ends=True,
                           segments=segments,
                           radius=1)
circ2 = bops.create_circle(bm,
                           cap_ends=True,
                           segments=segments,
                           radius=2)

# get their respective faces
end1 = circ1["verts"][0].link_faces[0]
end2 = circ2["verts"][0].link_faces[0]

# debug
print(end1.edges) # <BMElemSeq object at 0x12ec08600>
print(end2.edges) # <BMElemSeq object at 0x12ec08600>
print(end1.edges[0]) # <BMEdge(0x7ff3cc8963f0), index=6, verts=(0x7ff3d03a91a0/23, 0x7ff3d03a8f38/12)>
print(end2.edges[0]) # <BMEdge(0x7ff3cc8961c0), index=2, verts=(0x7ff3d03a8cd0/1, 0x7ff3d03a8d08/2)>
```

`end1.edges` and `end2.edges` are reportedly at the same address, but `end1.edges[0]` and `end2.edges[0]` point to different places. What's going on here?

Comment: This is most likely a C address. Try id(end1.edges) and id(end2.edges) which should be different.